# split command on Ubuntu command-line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, shell

I want to split a file into multiple files with at most 25 lines each.

I'm using this:

```
split -l 25 /etc/adduser.conf > /home/ubuntu/PL/trab3/rc_
```

But I do not get the files I expect.

How can I get files with filenames like rc_01, rc_02, etc.?

Answer (score 8):

Redirection (the `>` sign) is handled by the shell, and it can only output to a single file, the file you name.  Omit the `>`, so that `/home/ubuntu/PL/trab3/rc_` is passed to `split` as a command line argument, so that it can use that as its output prefix.

Comment: PS: Instead of just saying that something "doesn't work," it's better to say what happens... what error message(s) you get, what happens that you weren't expecting, what doesn't happen that you were expecting, etc.

Comment: `split --help` would help also

Answer (score 1):

Split doesn't support suffix for output file names. AFAIK it supports only prefix. For text files, you could try awk:

awk 'NR%25==1 { i+=1;file = "/home/ubuntu/PL/trab3/rc" "_" sprintf("%02d", i) } { print > file }' /etc/adduser.conf